# Adding property in Observable data before returning through connect function of angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material table.Inside connect function I am returning an observable of type patient. But I have to update the value of patientData  observable before returning .I have to add a "Active property if the patient id exist in redrows array.

connect function of data table

```
connect(): Observable<Patient[]> {
    const patientData = this.patientService.getPatient();

    patientData.subscribe((jsonData) => {
      const redRows = this.getAge(jsonData);
      for (let a = 0; a < jsonData.length; a++) {
        if (redRows.includes(jsonData[a].id)) {
          jsonData[a].active = 'Active';
        } else {
          jsonData[a].active = 'Not Active';
        }
      }
      return jsonData;

    },
      (err) => console.error(err),

      () => console.log('observable complete'));
    return patientData;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying data and returning from `subscription` won't change the observable, don't `subscribe()` in `connect()`. Use [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator from `rxjs` to modify data.

```
import { map} from "rxjs/operators"

connect(): Observable<Patient[]> {
    return this.patientService.getPatient().pipe(
        map((jsonData) => {
            const redRows = this.getAge(jsonData);
            for (let a = 0; a < jsonData.length; a++) {
                if (redRows.includes(jsonData[a].id)) {
                    jsonData[a].active = 'Active';
                } else {
                    jsonData[a].active = 'Not Active';
                }
            }
            return jsonData;
        })
    )
}
```

`subscribe` to `connect()` wherever you are using it.

Comment: @SoumyaBajpai: would you be kind to accept the answer if it works :D